# objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Buen día.

Estoy trabajando con viewbag´s en asp.net mvc pero me dice que me devuelve con objeto no establecido como instancia de un objeto. Pero si me muestra la info que quiero, cuando voy a la pantalla que muestra esa info, lo hace sin problemas pero cuando le doy click a un boton que genera otra acción me manda al codigo y me marca ese error (del titulo).

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Referencia a objeto no
> establecida como instancia de un objeto. Descripción: Excepción no
> controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento
> de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se
> originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a
> objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Línea 119:                ViewBag.Reasignacion =
> db.SolicitudReasignaciones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SolicitudId == id &
> x.ParaAgente.Correo == correo & x.Activo == true & (x.Aceptada ==
> false & x.Rechazada == false)); Línea 120: Línea 121:
> ViewBag.Motivo = db.SolicitudReasignaciones.FirstOrDefault(x =>
> x.SolicitudId == id & x.Aceptada == false & x.Rechazada ==
> false).Motivo; Línea 122:                  Línea 123:

así tengo el viewBag:

```
ViewBag.Motivo = db.SolicitudReasignaciones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SolicitudId == id & x.Aceptada == false & x.Rechazada == false).Motivo;
```

Y pues para que muestre el dato que quiero desde la bd mediante el id de la solicitud.

Comment: El `ViewBag` no persiste entre peticiones. Esto quiere decir, que si intentas acceder a él desde otra acción, muy probablemente tengas la excepción que reportas, porque la info ya no existe. Qué es lo que intentas hacer? cuál es el objetivo que deseas lograr? Tal vez `ViewData` o `ViewBag` no sean la mejor opción... O tal vez sí. Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade lo que quieres lograr, tal vez obtengas otras opiniones.

Comment: Es que mi problema tal vez sea sí estoy poniendo mal algo con la llamada al final de la variable

Comment: Si lo que buscas es persistir entre 2 peticiones: TempData en lugar de ViewBag, ojo que es importante que leas la documentación y seas consciente que también TempData es información no-persistente en más de 2 peticiones.

Comment: Yo una vez tuve el mismo problema, creo recordar que el error estaba en otro lado, pero por una extraña razón me generaba el error en el viewbag que si estaba instanciado